# Regex expression to detect phone number mistakes with URL that has numbers

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex

```
\(?(\+|0+)?\d{1,}\)?[- \.]?(\(\d+\))?[- \.]?\d{2,}[. -]? ?\d{2,}[ -\.]? ?\d{2,}
```

to detect various formats of phone numbers such as:

```
34565464
+93483227359
111-123-4567
+934-83227359
(111)123-4567
+1703.338.6512
+1 703 335 65123
001 (703) 332-6261 
Number: (111)123-4567
```

and it works great except the fact it confuses URLs such as:

https://www.google.com/search?q=**233066908**

How can I amend the expression to ignore URLs?

Comment: If you say it is in .NET, all you need is `Regex.Matches(text, @"https?://\S*|(<YOUR_PATTERN_HERE>)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a negative lookbehind is supported, you could check if the match is not preceded by a non whitespace char.

If you don't need the capturing groups for further processing, you could make them non capturing `(?:` and note that you don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

```
(?<!\S)\(?(?:\+|0+)?\d+\)?[- .]?(?:\(\d+\))?[- .]?\d{2,}[. -]? ?\d{2,}[ -.]? ?\d{2,}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLnGel/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
https?:\/\/.+|(\d{1,}\)?[- \.]?(\(\d+\))?[- \.]?\d{2,}[. -]? ?\d{2,}[ -\.]? ?\d{2,})
```

The trick is : consider the capture group a full match in case `http(s)://` is not contained in the parsed line (ie. `not "this"|(this)` pattern), and ignore matches when no capture group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought about it, but for some reason, I couldn't ignore the capture group in .Net, so I ended up using the other answer.